# Swiper continous auto scroll stops and starts and pause on mouse over not immediate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

I'm having an issue with Swiper and the slides not continuously scrolling in a linear smooth motion. Instead the slides pause and slow down and then start to speed up slightly before slowing again.

Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-autoplay-forked-9s2ccm?file=%2Findex.html%3A88%2C10).

I'd like the slides to loop in a continuous smooth motion, only pausing on mouse over. Similar to [this example](https://imgur.com/20AmT3f).

I've seen from this post [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/5841) this functionality was requested previously and its stated that this functionality has been added in since V9, but I cannot seeing any working examples since V9.

I'm using swiper version 10.0.2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    transition-timing-function: linear!important;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      max-width: 660px;
      background: red;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      spaceBetween: 40,
        effect: 'slide',
        loop: true,
        freeMode: true,
        slidesPerView: "auto",
        speed: 5000,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 1,
            pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
            waitForTransition: true,
            stopOnLastSlide: false,

        }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Overriding  the transition easing for `.swiper-wrapper` seems to solve the issue. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ExOXQdX)

Comment: Thank you that thats great and fixes the smooth transition. But it still doesn't stop on mouseover. If you click on an a slide it will stop the whole thing but it wont then re-start again and i only want it to pause on moveover not on click.

Comment: I surrender. According to plenty of github threads this seams to be an issue for quite some time. ... ever tried splide.js?

Comment: Thank you! Just implemented Splide.js and working perfectly.